# VB.NET-Keep the dropdownlist status without puting the code in "Not IsPostBack"

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, postback, status

I have 2 dropdownlists "countries" and "cities", with 2 datasources:

1. If a user chooses the first index in the ddl countries, he can see all the cities in the world in the ddl cities (uses datasource1).
2. If a user chooses a country, he can see the cities correspond to this country chosen (uses datasource2).
   I put the code for changing datasource in the code behind using vb.net, in Page_Load, but after the user chose a city, and click the submit button, the dropdownlist cities can't keep the status, it goes to the first index of this ddl.

I tried to put this code in the If Not IdPostBack, but like this, it doesn't change datasource while it can keep status of the dropdownlist.

So does anyone have an idea about this problem?

I put the code here as reference:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim ddlCities As DropDownList
Dim ddlCountries As DropDownList
ddlCities = CType(PN_Search.FindControl("DropDownList_Cities"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)
ddlCountries = CType(PN_Search.FindControl("DropDownList_Countries"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)
Dim countrySelect As String
countrySelect = ddlCountries.SelectedValue
Dim rechercheCitiesNull As String = "SELECT * FROM Cities WHERE id_city=1"
Dim rechercheCitiesNotNull As String = "SELECT * FROM [View_Country_City] Where id_country=" & countrySelect 

If countrySelect = "" Then
Me.RechercheCitiesDS.SelectCommand = rechercheCitiesNull
ddlCities.EnableViewState = True
ddlCountries.EnableViewState = True
ddlCities.DataBind()
ElseIf countrySelect <> "" Then
Me.RechercheCitiesDS.SelectCommand = rechercheCitiesNotNull
ddlCities.DataBind()

End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!
Ziliu

Answer (score 0):

EnableViewState and it should fix your issue. Keep your binding withing a not page.ispostback.

Comment: Hello David, I've tried to put databind in not ispostback, and also make the enableViewState equals True. But when I put it in ispostback, it doesn't change the datasource. Means no matter which country I choose, it always uses datasource1.

Comment: @zilu You need to change the datasource of your 2nd dropdown with the selectedinxedchanged event of your 1st dropdown. Make sure you specify autopostback=true in the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you so much, David. I managed to do it following your advice :)